# Bitrxix как подключить vue-select

Tags: vue.js, битрикс

Изучаю использование vue в Bitrix. Создал  расширение в /local/js . Настроил его. Но не могу понять и не нашел в документации как подключать внешние плагины к vue. Например хочу подключить vue-select, поставил плагин через npm install vue-select в папке с расширением. В компоненте написал

```
import {Vue} from 'ui.vue';
import VueSelect from '../../node_modules/vue-select/dist/vue-select'

Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect);
Vue.component('input-list', {
    data() {
        return {
            count: 0
        }
    },
    template: `
            <v-select :options="['Canada', 'United States']"></v-select>
    `
})
```

(node:26128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules\vue-select\dist\vue-select.js

Как все таки подключать ?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример того как подключаете vue-select

Comment: я добавил код в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подключать вот так:

```
import VueSelect from "vue-select";

Vue.component("v-select", VueSelect);
```

Или так:

```
import { VueSelect } from 'node_modules/vue-select/dist/vue-select';
Vue.component("v-select", VueSelect);
```

Comment: Спасибо получилось, поправил путь из второго варианта. Но полезли другие ошибки. Буду разбираться.